# CakePHP How to accomplish a NOT IN

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to accomplish a NOT IN clause in CakePHP, but I am not able to achieve it. I've been reading the CakePHP Cookbook and some answers here in StackOverflow but it's not working for me.

I have a Table named 'Hotel' with all its model, controller and views. In the view template I built a CakePHP Cell where I want to show other Hotels, except for the hotel that is currently being viewed. If for example, I am showing the view of a hotel with id #5, I want to show other hotels options, except for that hotel view id number.

I have the following query in the Cell Controller:

```
$hotels = $this->Hotels->find('all')
    ->where(['Hotels.id NOT IN' => $current_hotel_id])
    ->limit(4)
    ->order('rand()')
    ->toArray();
```

I want $current_hotel_id to have the value of current hotel that it's being viewed. That's the approach I am taking.

Any useful information would be appreciated.

Comment: I want $current_hotel_id to have the value of current hotel that it's being viewed. - then set it that way.

Comment: is it a sql question or how to pass arg to cell question

Comment: If I leave  ->where(['Hotels.id NOT IN' => 'Hotels.id']) the value that shows is always (0) for some reason, and not the current view id. So that doesn't work.

Comment: ['Hotels.id NOT IN' => 'Hotels.id']) so effectively WHERE ID!=ID  - how that is suppose to work??

Comment: I want to exclude the view that is currently being loaded. That's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: Why not use `'Hotels.id <>' => $current_hotel_id` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need some value that is available in your controller in cell, you must pass that value to it.

First, declare an argument in cell action:

```
class HotelsCell extends Cell{
    public function hotels($current_hotel_id){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Then, in your view, pass argument to cell:

```
$this->cell("Hotels::hotels",[$hotel->id])
```

More info in docs: [Passing Arguments to a Cell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#passing-arguments-to-a-cell)